# Issue with setting fontsize for bullets

Tags: html

I am using a innova/tinymce editor. If I select any bulleted/numbered text, I want the bullet/numbering size to change as per the text size. However though the selected text size increases, the bullets/numbers remain the same.Also it seems that the bullets/numbers do not get selected.
However if I change the font of the selected text, it gets applied to the bullets/numbers as well

I checked the html code generated

HTML code generated for bullets is like follows

< ol >

< li >< span style="font-size: xx-small;">abc< /span>< /li>

< li>< span style="font-size: x-small;">def< /span>< /li>

< /ol>

Here, styling applies only to content of < li> not to < li>

If I change above code as follows it works

< ol>
< li style="font-size: xx-small;">abc
< li style="font-size: x-small;">def

Is there any configuration/code changes using which the font size can be applied to the bullets/numbering as well.

Any inputs will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Style applied to OL element will be applied both to LI and to the text. If it's ok to style using HTML, then look at this solution:

```
<html>
<body>
    <ol style="font-size: 10px;">
        <li><span style="color: red;">Test1</span></li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
    </ol>
    <ol style="font-size: 20px;">
        <li>Test1</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is generated automatically by document.exec("fontsize"). This seems to be handled by the browser. Any way how we can change this code generated

Comment: Don't get you clearly, but guess that what are you talking about will be overridden if: 1. you assign an ID for the control and use this ID for styling control in external .css file; 2. you assign a custom style in WebControl properties - in that case .net will render html for this control with the style you defined.